# How to save active tab state?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

Is it possible to keep the currently active tab state so that the tab would stay active after page refresh?

Didn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Are you taking about tabs which you created during your plugin creation ? if so check this out - https://octobercms.com/docs/ui/tab

Comment: If you are talking about front-end, you can use viewbag: https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/components#viewbag-component

Comment: I'm asking about the backend :)

Comment: AFAIK, each tab is represented by a controller name in the url, so I don't see how the tab would not stay active after page refresh.